# How to Parse the Soap Response returning Map ( key and value pair ) in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, parsing, soap

I just make the Soap call of one web service and that gives the response me in one String that have data something like given below :

```
    [Map{
         item=anyType{key=customer_id; value=1; }; 
         item=anyType{key=created_at; value=2007-08-30 23:23:13; }; 
         item=anyType{key=updated_at; value=2008-08-08 12:28:24; }; 
         item=anyType{key=increment_id; value=000000001; }; 
         item=anyType{key=store_id; value=1; }; 
         item=anyType{key=website_id; value=1; }; 
         item=anyType{key=default_billing; value=274; }; 
         item=anyType{key=default_shipping; value=274; }; 
         item=anyType{key=disable_auto_group_change; value=0; }; 
         item=anyType{key=email; value=john.doe@example.com; }; 
         item=anyType{key=firstname; value=John; }; 
         item=anyType{key=group_id; value=1; }; 
         item=anyType{key=lastname; value=Doe; }; 
         item=anyType{key=middlename; value=; }; 
         item=anyType{key=password_hash; value=2049484a4020ed15d0e4238db22977d5:eg; }; 
         item=anyType{key=prefix; value=; }; 
         item=anyType{key=suffix; value=; }; 
         item=anyType{key=taxvat; value=; };
```

}]

so I just tried so many resources to parse this response like JSON, Vector, Enumeration, Map, HashMap.....  but i cant parse this response,

this is not the JSON response, but still I tried to parse the data with JSON, but I cant...

what is the best way to parse such a response ?

does anybody know how to do this ?

thanks......

Comment: Cant you use SOAP for communication with web service? Also still you use JSON I think here is some kind of String processing required. Is it ?

Comment: @andunslg: thanks for answer , i have used soap in this application, i am not using JSON, this is the response string of Soap Call.... I need to parse this string and need to get the data.....

Comment: Ahha then you can do some string processing I think. Do you need a specific library kind of a thing to do it other than normal string manipulations ?

Comment: yes, If some library is available then its easy to parse the data for this type of response......

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class **SoapMap** like this:

```
class SoapMap
{
    SoapObject soapObject;
    Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public SoapMap(SoapObject soapObject)
    {
        this.soapObject = soapObject;
        for(int i=0; i<soapObject.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {
            String str = soapObject.getProperty(i).toString();
            String key = str.split("key=")[1].split(";")[0];
            String value = str.split("value=")[1].split(";")[0];            
            pairs.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String key)
    {
        return pairs.get(key);
    }
}
```

and use the SoapMap like:

```
SoapMap soapMap = new SoapMap(yourSoapObjectResponse);
int customer_id = Integer.parseInt( soapMap.getValue("customer_id") );
String firstname = soapMap.getValue("firstname");
String email = soapMap.getValue("email");
```